# Get Object List from Session and Iterate without using JSTL

Tags: list, jsp, session, getattribute

What I want to try is set the attribute of `List <Object>` in the session from my controller. Then in my jsp file get the Object List from the session and display the list values through a loop.

**My Controller**

```
//RecordView recordViewSingle = dao.getRecords();
//request.getSession().setAttribute("SingleRecord", recordViewSingle);
List <RecordView> recordView = dao.getRecordDetails();
request.getSession().setAttribute("AllRecord", recordView);
```

**JSP**

```
<%
    //RecordView data = (RecordView)session.getAttribute("SingleRecord");
    List <RecordView> data = (RecordView)session.getAttribute("AllRecord");
%>

<table>
...
...
    <% for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i+=1) { %>
        <tr>      
            <td><%=data.get(i).getDataID()%></td>
            <td><%=data.get(i).getDataName()%></td>
            <td><%=data.get(i).getLastDate()%></td>
        </tr>
    <% } %>

...
...
</table>
```

But getting error says that: `List cannot be resolved to a type` and pointing the code below:

```
List <RecordView> data = (RecordView)session.getAttribute("AllRecord");
```

I can run this program successfully if I use single `Object` but not when using the `list <Object>` Please help me to fix this. And also correct me if the way I used to retrive data in the table is wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. Made two mistakes. First is I forgot to IMPORT `util.List` at the top. And the second mistake was it should be

```
List <RecordView> data = (List<RecordView>)session.getAttribute("AllRecord");
```

instead of using this

```
List <RecordView> data = (RecordView)session.getAttribute("AllRecord");
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is an error mentioning "Cannot be resolved to a type" - Always remember it is either misspelled or it has a missing import. In your case just give it a check if you have missed the import

Second point is - your casting

```
<%
    //RecordView data = (RecordView)session.getAttribute("SingleRecord");
    List <RecordView> data = (RecordView)session.getAttribute("AllRecord");
%>
```

The casting should be (List)session.getAttribute("AllRecord");

Hope this helps